# How to draw only visible area with QQuickPaintedItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to plot many data as lines with **QQuickPaintedItem**.

```
Flickable
{
  /* small width and height */
  MyPaintedItem
  { /* large width and height */ }
}
```

Then I got a performance issue caused by CPU.
There is only very few data on screen at the same time.
How can I draw only visible area with **QQuickPaintedItem** *without passing* visibleArea of **Flickable** to **MyPaintedItem**?

Comment: Not sure about Qt Quick, but in Qt Widgets QPainters are usually clipped to the visible or dirty area. Try reading the `clipRegion` from your painter.

Comment: @SteakOverflow clipRegion is always QRectF(0,0 0x0) on Qt Quick

Comment: "How can I draw only visible area with QQuickPaintedItem without passing visibleArea of Flickable to MyPaintedItem?" => Afaik, that would be possible with scrying only. Maybe randomly with guessing. Theoretically everything is `visible` when it is drawn to the render target or image. Only when you arrange the stuff on the SG, it becomes apparent what is not clipped or occluded.

Comment: Did you find any answers to this yet? Would be nice if you could post your comments if you have found another plausible solution

Comment: @itapadar No. I use raw OpenGL instead.